# Python count dictionary inside list with same value

Tags: python

I have dicts like this :

```
list_dicts = [
    {
        'code': 'A1', 'name': 'White',
    },
    {
        'code': 'A2', 'name': 'Black',
    },
    {
        'code': 'A1', 'name': 'White',
    },
    {
        'code': 'A3', 'name': 'Red',
    }
]
```

And how to get dicts look like this from above dicts ?

```
list_dicts = [
    {
        'code': 'A1', 'name': 'White', 'qty': 2
    },
    {
        'code': 'A2', 'name': 'Black', 'qty': 1
    },
    {
        'code': 'A3', 'name': 'Red', 'qty': 1
    }
]
```

..........................

Comment: Don't you mean `A3, Red, 1` for the last result? Take a look at `collections.Counter()` and consider just the `.values()` of the `dict`. Is this meant to be a list of dicts, because currently it is just one `dict`.

Comment: Your dict is valid but repeats keys. Did you mean it to be a list of dict rather than one dict with repeated keys?

Comment: Your current dictionary right now is only : `[{'code': 'A3', 'name': 'Red'}]`

Comment: Sorry it's my fault.

Comment: dictionary keys have to be unique. Otherwise you'll end up with @shash678 pointed out.

Comment: "And how to get dictionary like this ?" Answer: with a script. I don't see any here, are expecting us to write it for you?

Comment: haha, sorry for my english, my english is weak..

Answer (score 5):

Assuming that you actually have a list of dicts:

```
list_dict = [
    {'code': 'A1', 'name': 'White'},
    {'code': 'A2', 'name': 'Black'},
    {'code': 'A1', 'name': 'White'},
    {'code': 'A3', 'name': 'Red'}
]
```

Then you can use `collections.Counter` to count the values:

```
In []:
from collections import Counter
Counter((x['code'], x['name']) for x in list_dict)

Out[]:
Counter({('A1', 'White'): 2, ('A2', 'Black'): 1, ('A3', 'Red'): 1})
```

It's a fairly easy exercise to turn this back into the list of dictionaries you are looking for.

Answer (score 0):

Just use a [`defaultdict`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.defaultdict) to store the counts of each `(code, name)`:

```
from collections import defaultdict

list_dict = [{'code': 'A1', 'name': 'White'},
             {'code': 'A2', 'name': 'Black'},
             {'code': 'A1', 'name': 'White'},
             {'code': 'A3', 'name': 'Red'},
            ]

d = defaultdict(int)
for dic in list_dict:
    key = dic['code'], dic['name']
    d[key] += 1

>>> print(dict(d))
{('A1', 'White'): 2, ('A2', 'Black'): 1, ('A3', 'Red'): 1}
```

Then just create a new list, and insert the new data from the dictionary above:

```
new_dict_list = [{'code':code, 'name':name, 'qty':qty} for (name, code), qty in d.items()]

>>> print(new_dict_list)
[{'code': 'A1', 'name': 'White', 'qty': 2}, {'code': 'A2', 'name': 'Black', 'qty': 1}, {'code': 'A3', 'name': 'Red', 'qty': 1}]
```

Comment: if I have other key in dict and I want to get value?

Comment: @ArifMustaqim I don't understand you're question.

Comment: list_dict = [{'code': 'A1', 'name': 'White', 'nb': 'Pure White', ....},
             {'code': 'A2', 'name': 'Black', 'nb': 'Black Pink', ....},
             {'code': 'A1', 'name': 'White', 'nb': 'White Blue', ....},
             {'code': 'A3', 'name': 'Red', 'nb': 'Red Black', ....},
            ]
How do I get value from another key?